# TrackedPropertiesEvaluationFailed error in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a really frustrating issue with a logic app

All I am trying to do is to parse the Json of my http request that comes into the logic app and add 2 properties as tracked properties

I get the totally useless error

```
TrackedPropertiesEvaluationFailed
```

I dont understand why the error message cannot be more descriptive as this is totally useless

I have tried loads of different ways and nothing works

My body is

```
{
   "eventType":"order.statusChanged",
   "resource":{
      "status":"Committed",
   }
}
```

I think the correct syntax is

```
"@triggerBody()?['status']"
```

which I put onto a tracked property called paymentStatus but I just get this error

What am I doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are receiving this error due to syntatic error.

Post removing the syntatical error here is the JSON

```
{
    "properties": {
        "eventType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "resource": {
            "properties": {
                "status": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Here is the tracker properties expression we have used to pull the payment status

```
"@body('Parse_JSON')?['resource']?['status']"
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]